# The named parameter isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently learning Flutter and I'm very new to it. I'm trying to make a decreasement counter next to the increment counter in the default code. I wrote another void for decreasing and wrote the code same to increment (except incrementing) but it gives error:

> The named parameter 'bulutunKatiliRota' isn't defined.
>   Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter, or defining a new parameter with this name.dart(undefined_named_parameter)

The code (I'm only writing the code that i added):

```
void _decreaseCounter(){
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

bulutunKatiliRota: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _decreaseCounter,
        tooltip: 'Decrease',
        child: Icon(Icons.delete)
      )
```

Comment: Instead of `bulutunKatiliRota` use `floatingActionButton`.

Comment: there is another button uses the same name

Comment: If you wish to use multiple FAB, then include them using a `Column` and give each FAB a unique `key`

Comment: can you be more specific? i'm very very new to flutter

Comment: I can definitely help but first let me what is `bulutunKatiliRota` and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a button that decreases number from `_counter` variable. I already made a button that increases the valiable but decreasing is not working.

Comment: So, there are going to be text that shows `_counter` variable and two buttons that decreases and increases `_counter_`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace your `floatingActionButton` with this:

```
floatingActionButton: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    FloatingActionButton( // first FAB to perform decrement 
      onPressed: _decrementCounter,
      child: Icon(Icons.delete),
    ),
    FloatingActionButton( // second FAB to perform increment
      onPressed: _incrementCounter,
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ],
)
```